# Accessing Erlang/Elixir node inside MiniKube pod

Tags: erlang, elixir, kubernetes, minikube

I've got `Deployment` which has `n` nodes and I have service that exposes `4369`. I want to connect to one of those nodes via IEX. I am using `MiniKube` for my local development `Kubernetes` cluster which binds to some IP and I `can` access it's dashboard.

I tried calling `minikube service thatServiceName`, but after few moments of w8ing it ends work and `does not output` link that it supposed to give me.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: erlangpl-demo-mnesia
  labels:
    app: erlangpl-demo-mnesia
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 10000
      targetPort: 10000
      name: disterl-mesh-0
    - port: 4369
      targetPort: 4369
      name: epmd
  selector:
    app: erlangpl-demo-mnesia
  type: ClusterIP
```

Could anyone let me know what am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type: ClusterIP` with `clusterIP: None` looks fishy to me. I do not think that minikube provides support for that service type.

I would try using `type: NodePort`, which should expose the service on the minikube IP.

Comment: It is almost working.. Now the problem is that MiniKube forwards port to some crazy high number.

Comment: The nodePort should be allocated in the range 30000-32767 by default.

You should be able to add on to `minikube start`
 `--extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=10000-60000` for example.

Comment: That's what I did. I forced it to bind to 4369 with NodePort: 4369, but still can't connect.

Comment: Dunno what to tell you. I'm not familiar with elixir/iex. If you have an updated repro to try, I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the pod directly:

```
kubectl exec -it your-pod-name
```

it defaults to bash, which I didn't had so I have to do:

```
kubectl exec -it your-pod-name -- /bin/sh
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah it works that way, but I am missing autocompletion and it is a bit annoying.